# Client certificate authentication for two websites

Tags: authentication, ssl, https, x509certificate, x509

I have deployed two websites in IIS and both of these websites contain some services which client systems are going to use.
I have implemented client certificate authentication in both of these and configured the oneToOneCertificateMapping.
I created two separate client certificates and configured one for each website.
Now the problem I am facing is both of these certificates are working for both the websites, even though I have added only one for each.

Note: In the configuration Editor I have made this configuration under the web.config files of individual websites, not in the ApplicationHost.Config

This is how the config file looks for both websites:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" manyToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="false">
                    <oneToOneMappings>
                        <add userName="XXXXXX" password="[enc:AesProvider:XXXXXXXX:enc]" certificate="XXXX" />
                    </oneToOneMappings>
                </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
 <location path="web.config">
  <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="true" defaultLogonDomain="XXXX">
                    <oneToOneMappings>
                        <add userName="XXX" password="[enc:AesProvider:XXXXX:enc]" certificate="XXXX" />
                    </oneToOneMappings>
                </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Please help. My requirement is that, only the specified certificate should pass the authentication, not the other one.

Comment: Can you show the configuration you are talking about? Perhaps with it I can help you.

Comment: @AlexanderMeise I have added the snippet from the web.config file. I wonder why  <system.webServer> is present twice, first directly and then under the  <location path="web.config"> tag.

Comment: I am not sure of the solution ...  did you try to put this in the web.config of the each site? (each config to the corresponding site).